# after primefaces filterby selected var get lost

Tags: primefaces, filter, datatable, actionlistener

After filtering with `filterBy` selected `var` instance get lost.

```xml
<p:dataTable id="searchResults"
             var="searchResult"
             value="#{employeeController.searchResults}"
             selectionMode="single"
             selection="#{employeeController.selectedEmployee}"
             rowKey="#{searchResult.id}">
    <p:column headerText="Employee Name"
              filterBy="#{searchResult.name}"
              sortBy="#{searchResult.name}">
        <h:outputText value="#{searchResult.name}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>


<p:commandButton actionListener="#{employeeController.editEmployee(searchResult)}"
                 icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                 title="Güncelle" ajax="true" update="@form">
```

my event does not get the selected `searchResult` instance but instead a `null` value

Comment: Your `var` field is only accessible inside `p:dataTable` hence `null` because it does not exist outside. Does it work without `filterBy`?

Comment: it seems filteredValue inside of datatable. could you check it

Comment: thank you very much the problem was missing filteredValue

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I was just missing `filteredValue`.